# How drill polyurethane properly?

Tags: drill, polyurethane

I am building an electric skateboard for which I bought a pulley with a belt that will transfer torque from the motor. This pulley is mounted on a wheel with 5 M3 screws and here is the problem. All skate- or longboard wheels are polyurethane and it turned out to be really nasty to drill. I tried to do it by hand with my screwdriver, but drill bit walks around a lot before penetrating and inclines very easily from drilling axle. And if it did incline, it is almost impossible to drill a hole just next to the previous. I tried freezing the wheel, but it doesn't really make any difference.

So the question is how to drill polyurethane properly? Lubrication fluid? Speed recommendation? General tipps on processing such materials?

.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the diy Stack Exchange.  Are you certain it is correct to be drilling the soft complaint part of the wheel to mount the pully? I did a quick search in Amazon looking at electric skate board conversion kits and I noted that applicable wheels have a larger hard plastic hub. Some have 10 holes that appear to permit a 5 hole pully to be mounted through these hub holes. Other types have five slots in this hub which can accept tabs on some of the wheel pully units. Your drilling problem may very well be dealt with by getting the proper type of wheels for the skate board.

Answer (score 2):

Polyurethane can be drilled with a common high-speed twist drill. It seems as though your issue is more related to the shape of the surface rather than the material.

To stop a bit from "walking" you should be using a punch or awl to create a small divot at the intended drill location. It may help to start with a much smaller bit size, then increase bit size in step until reaching needed hole diameter.

Your issues with difficulty drilling adjacent holes, and "incline... from drilling angle (sic)" are related to the method. The piece should be clamped securely when drilling, so it cannot move, and you should be using a drill press (or at least a drill guide) if precise drill angle and depth are needed.

Comment: Shape makes it more tricky as it has some slope. I wanted to say it is difficult to drill relatively to wood for example. I mean it's common to use guide, punch and increasing-drill-diameter method. Though I have no press and no clamps.
Anyway I think it's possible to make a small divot, but with a hot nail or something, but regarding my previous experience it would not be enough I guess. 
And what about speed?

Comment: Good question- some people think that when their bit says "high speed" that it means "light speed", it doesn't. A lower speed with a twist drill just means it will take longer, it doesn't hurt anything; conversely, very high speed will burn up the drill due to heat and make ineffecient cutting due to inability of flutes to clear tailings.

Comment: Luckily I can control speed with a trigger. What would be reccomeded speed for such material? Maybe I should also try a drill for wood?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you may not be on the right track for mounting your wheel pulley. I did a little bit of research on the subject of electric skate board DIY conversion kits and find that the wheels used seem to have hard plastic center hubs and then the more flexible rubber material wheel molded onto the hub. I saw wheels that this hard plastic hub has 10 holes through which a pulley can be mounted simply by using five long bolts through every other one of the hub holes. The other type I saw the wheel's plastic hub has five slots and then the wheel pulley compatible with that has five finger tabs designed to press into the hub slots.

Comment: Well, these solutions are indeed out there, but cost extra. I just went another way around and made everything myself. I printed the housing for wheel pulley and the back holding plug. The only thing I need to do now is some nice drilling.